# How to connect to TFS 2012 in a local network?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012

I have this scenario in my local network:

[picture] http://fekt.datagrid.sk/DATA/stackoverflow/scenario.PNG

Windows 2012:
Only IIS installed and configured, TFS installed and configured.

TFS configuration:

[picture] http://fekt.datagrid.sk/DATA/stackoverflow/config.PNG

When I run Visual Studio 2012 on win2012 machine, everything works perfect.
I can check-in, check-out changes, i can go to web access(http://win2012:8080/tfs)

From Desktop PC (Win8, VS2012) I can not connecto to TFS.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try access web access from your machine?

Comment: Are you able to ping the TFS server from your workstation? (This would lead you to discovering issues with DNS)  Is there an Active Directory domain controller in this environment and are both the server and workstation joined to the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely the windows firewall.

I would suggest you add the port in question and application to the windows firewall exception rules.

You can quickly test by turning it off but remember to turn it on again once you have tested.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a DNS or WINS issue?
Try to ping win2012 from your desktop PC.
Maybe you can try use IP to access the TFS by http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/tfs